# How to handle pdo exception error gracefully for user experience

Tags: 7, entities

Integer fileds can accidentally be entered with 'Out of range' error. This time a user has no other option but to click back button.
Any suggestions on templating these kinds of errors or for any other errors of the same nature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What? ... add a custom FAPI validator to your forms so there is no out-of-range error.

You could build on, or start off by using:
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/element_validate_integer/7